# sge-pygame rotating parent and child sprites

Tags: python, rotation, pygame, 2d

I have been researching and trying to figure this out for quite awhile. I am attempting to create a parent/child attaching system so that when the parent moves, the children attached to it move/rotate/scales the same. The main issue I'm having is with rotation.

This is the code I currently use for the children:

```
def _rotate(self, origin, point, angle):
  ox, oy = origin
  px, py = point

  qx = ox + math.cos(angle) * (px - ox) - math.sin(angle) * (py - oy)
  qy = oy + math.sin(angle) * (px - ox) + math.cos(angle) * (py - oy)

  return qx, qy
```

The _rotate code rotates a 2D point the angle around the origin point that I found while searching for an answer to my problem. The points I'm using are the center of each boxes/sprites.

When rotating the parent, I use the sge-pygame image_rotation and then move on to the children positioning. After which I need to figure out the rotation of the children based on the new position and the new angle to rotate the child.

Images of what happens:

Initial
[image]

and

Rotated 10deg
[image]

Parent is the large rectangle and the box is the child.

The second issue I am having is with figuring out what the rotation angle of the child would be to keep it inline with the parent. I found out through stackflow that the use of math.atan2 is supposed to be used for this however I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I can't post an answer right now but here are some tips: 1. To rotate the child, move its pivot point to its parent's pivot point and apply the exact rotation as you did to the parent. 2. Then use the parents direction vector (if you don't have a direction vector you could create one from cos(angle), sin(angle)) and then move the child with `direction * offset`, where *offset* is the distance from the parent's pivot point to where you want the child to be located.

Comment: @ted Alright, I've figured out using the first part. It's the direction vector and moving the child I seem to be having issues with. I'll keep trying to work it out while waiting for your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with rotating both the parent and child the same amount (in this example it's assumed that parent should be controlled while child should not). Then you just move the child to the parent's pivot point (in this case its center) and an extra offset in the direction that the parent is facing (the offset is of course optional).

```
from math import cos, sin, radians
import pygame
pygame.init()

SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 720, 480
BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color('black')
FPS = 60

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def update_child_rotation(parent, child, degrees, offset):
    # Rotate the parent and child with the same angle.
    parent.rotate(degrees)
    child.rotate(degrees)

    # Calculate the direction the parent is pointing. If you remember the unit circle then you'll
    # know that cos(angle) represent the x value and sin(angle) the y value. At angle = 0 the direction
    # is to the right (which is what your sprite should be pointing, otherwise you'll have to add an angle
    # offset), and it rotates counterclockwise. The minus in '-sin' is because pygame uses positive y as downwards.
    angle_in_radians = radians(parent.angle)
    direction = pygame.math.Vector2(cos(angle_in_radians), -sin(angle_in_radians))

    # Update the child's position to the parent's position but with an added offset in the direction the parent
    # is pointing.
    child.position = parent.position + direction * offset


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, position, size):
        super().__init__()

        self.original_image = pygame.Surface(size)
        self.original_image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.original_image.set_colorkey(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=position)

        self.angle = 0
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(position)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

    def rotate(self, degrees):
        self.angle = (self.angle + degrees) % 360
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.position)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.position += self.velocity
        self.rect.center = self.position


def main():
    parent = Entity(position=(200, 200), size=(128, 32))
    child = Entity(position=(356, 200), size=(32, 32))
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(parent, child)

    running = True
    while running:

        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    update_child_rotation(parent, child, 10, 156)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_e:
                    update_child_rotation(parent, child, -10, 156)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    parent.velocity.x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    parent.velocity.y = 0

        all_sprites.update(dt)

        screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the pivot and the desired offset to the child during the instantiation (I use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2)s in the example below). If the parent moves, update all of its children (I stored them in a list) and pass them the velocity of the parent which they can use to update their positions as well.

The rotation works similarly, you just need to pass the angle to the children, then rotate their offset vectors and images and set the center of the new rect to the old center plus the offset.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((90, 40), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('steelblue2'))
        self.orig_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.angle = 0
        # A list that holds all children instances.
        self.children = [Child(self.pos, Vector2(90, 30), *groups)]

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        for child in self.children:
            child.move(self.vel)

    def rotate(self, angle):
        self.angle += angle
        # Rotate the image and generate a new rect to keep it centered.
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        # Rotate the children.
        for child in self.children:
            child.rotate(angle)


class Child(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, offset, *groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 30), pg.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('mediumaquamarine'))
        self.orig_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)  # Parent center.
        # Offset from parent center.
        self.offset = Vector2(offset)
        self.angle = 0

    def move(self, vel):
        self.pos += vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos + self.offset

    def rotate(self, angle):
        # Rotate the offset vector (negative angle otherwise it would
        # rotate in the wrong direction).
        self.offset.rotate_ip(-angle)
        self.angle += angle
        # Rotate the image.
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.orig_image, self.angle)
        # Add the new offset to the center.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center + self.offset)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    sprite_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((100, 250), sprite_group)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 5
                elif event.key == pg.K_r:
                    player.rotate(15)
                elif event.key == pg.K_c:
                    player.children.append(Child(
                        player.pos, Vector2(-90, -30), sprite_group))
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.vel.x = 0

        sprite_group.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprite_group.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Press 'd' to move to the right, 'r' to rotate and 'c' to add more children.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SGE. Does it allow you to use pygame sprites, sprite groups and vectors? If not, you can probably adjust the code according to your requirements.